# On the isomorphism $\text{U}(p, q) \cong \text{U}(q,p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

By definition, I know that the indefinite unitary group of signature $(p, q)$ is $$\text{U}(p, q):= \{g \in \text{GL}(p+q,\mathbb{C}): g^{*}I_{p,q}g= I_{p,q}\}\text{,} $$ where $I_{p,q}$ is the diagonal $(p+q)\times (p+q) $ matrix with $p$ $+1$s and $q$ $-1$s, and $g^{*}$ is the conjugate transpose of $g$. Evidently,  $\text{U}(p, q) \cong \text{U}(q,p)$, but why is that? Is it because interchanging $p$ and $q$ is the same as replacing the metric by its negative, giving the same group? This is exactly the argument used for the indefinite orthogonal group $\text{O}(p,q)$ at the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group

Comment: Yes, indeed, your surmise is correct.